# Помогите разобраться в фильтре wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно в чем дело, я делаю фильтр по мета полю содержащему массив с метками подскажите почему нечего не выводится даже когда я подставляю все значения одного поста, ведь он должен вывести этот один пост. Вот код

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'kursy',
'showposts'=> 100 ,
'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key' => 'выбор_разделов',
                    'value' => get_post_meta(8652 , 'выбор_разделов', true),
      ),
  ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
```

Comment: для начала составьте запрос, который вам нужен для mysql, а дальше через конструкцию wp, которую вы используете, вы сами увидите где у вас ошибка

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я не знаю как это делать) Я слабо знаю php и не понимаю о каком запросе идет речь)

Comment: нужно начинать с самого простого, а не сразу браться за cms т.к они используют свои конструкции для запросов, а как новичку правильно составить запрос сразу с конструкцией wp как? мне не понятно, вполне возможно я бы столкнулся с такими же проблемами что и у вас, я пишу о том, какие бы шаги я предпринял, чтобы решить такую задачу. Немного теории для отображения статей/новостей/постов и т.д выполняется запрос в бд, sql запрос вида SELECT * from posts, у вас конструктор формируется в массиве $args и передаётся в new WP_Query где он собирается и выполняется

Comment: я предлагаю вам составить sql запрос в бд, который вам нужен, а значение из фильтра у вас будет переменная в php, вполне возможно при написании sql вы поймёте, чего вам не хватает в выборке и поправите это, если не понятно как делать запрос к бд этого полно в гугле + мой совет гляньте как работать с объектом WP_Query

Comment: я понимаю почему не работает, но не понимаю как это сделать, запрос я создаю правильный, а не работает он потому что там массив а как сравнивать элементы массива я не понимаю, я уверен что там есть какое то очень простое решение, в пару строчек, ведь все обычные мета поля выводятся нормально

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh совет плохой, потому что человек работает уже в cms, и никуда от этого не деться. Он не сможет сравнить свой успешный запрос к БД (даже если осилит его создание) с тем, что генерирует WordPress, потому что WP создаёт весьма сложный для понимания запрос к базе. Так сделано для реализации самых разнообразных возможностей, заложенных в ядро. Функции WP как раз созданы для того, чтобы облегчить и упростить жизнь разработчику.

Comment: `show_posts` устарел очень давно (хотя всё ещё поддерживается), вместо него надо использовать `posts_per_page`. Задайте `posts_per_page => -1` для вывода всех постов. Дело, конечно, не в этом. Что у вас выводит `var_dump(get_post_meta(8652 , 'выбор_разделов', true));` ?

Comment: Выводит массив с значениями мета поля

Comment: Так в этом как раз дело. Массивы хранятся в сериализованном виде. MySQL не умеет с ними работать. Я делал нечто подобное (хранил массивы в мета), посмотрите класс `KAGG_List_In_Meta::` в моём плагине https://wordpress.org/plugins/notification-system/

Comment: Так я и понимаю что дело в этом) но как это решить ? для меня это сложно я так обычно верстаю и на wp натягиваю изредка что то сам пишу и то больше на js а php совсем мало

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я разобрался как это все устроить, всем спасибо

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'kursy',
'showposts'=> 100 ,
'meta_query' =>array(
  array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'vibor',
      'value'   => serialize('1'),
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
      ),
    ),
);
```